Sidebar menus in react do not get updated until a hot build
I have a sidebar which is populated via an array of menu items. Below is the code for the data.jsx
import AdminPanelSettingsOutlined from "@mui/icons-material/AdminPanelSettingsOutlined";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  HomeIcon,
  LayoutIcon,
  CalendarIcon,
  InvoiceIcon,
  UserIcon,
  RolesIcon,
  PagesIcon,
  AuthIcon,
  WizardIcon,
  ModalIcon,
} from "./Icons";
import keycloakService from "../KeycloakService"
export const SIDEBAR_DATA = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Home",
    path: "/secured",
    icon:<HomeIcon/>,
    visibility: 'true'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Administration",
    path: "/Administration",
    icon:<AdminPanelSettingsOutlined/>,
    visibility: await keycloakService.hasRole(['NexaAdmin']) == true ? 'true' : 'false'
    
  },
  
];

The data.jsx is being called in Sidebaritems.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  ItemsList,
  ItemContainer,
  ItemWrapper,
  ItemName,
} from "./SidebarStyles";

import { dummyData } from "..";

const SidebarItems = ({ displaySidebar }) => {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(0);
  const [showItem, setShowItem] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ItemsList>
      {dummyData.map((itemData, index) => (
        
        itemData.visibility == 'true' && <ItemContainer
          key={index}
          onClick={() => setActiveItem(itemData.id)}
          className={itemData.id === activeItem ? "active" : ""}

        >

          <Link to={itemData.path}>
            <ItemWrapper>
              {itemData.icon}
              <ItemName displaySidebar={displaySidebar}>
                {itemData.name} {itemData.visibility}
              </ItemName>
            </ItemWrapper>
          </Link>
        </ItemContainer>
      ))}
    </ItemsList>
  );
};

export default SidebarItems;

My problem is the menu items are rendered without considering the visibility role in the data.jsx. It only get updated once I do a small change and save it, pretty much a hot update. Any ideas what could be wrong with my code. Can provide more code if needed

you should check the value of visibility variable (try console.log)
because your promise may be unresolved and unresolved promises are truthy

I do a get true/false depending on the rule but after the hot update. Before that its blank or empty string

You might need to store this data on the client side somewhere within state, then?
